# Is it possible to make a background ViewController unclickable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

So I've got a `UIActivityViewController` that takes up half the screen when my app runs, what happens is when I click the half it doesn't take up then it'll disappear and my original blank `ViewController` appears.

Is it possible to permanently keep the `UIActivityView` up until the user clicks on one of the sharing options (such as `Facebook`, or `Mail`)? Otherwise I'll just work around it.

I load the ActivityView with:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[@""] applicationActivities:nil]; 

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use tap gesture for this

Comment: Whatever view you want to block interaction put `someView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` then, when you close your activity indicator put `someView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can try something like

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showAViewController) name:@"showAViewController" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dissmissAViewController) name:@"dissmissAViewController" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"showAViewController" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"dissmissAViewController" object:nil];
}

-(void)showAViewController{
self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
}

-(void)dissmissAViewController{
self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
}
```

When you are showing a view controller on top of another view controller just call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAViewController" object:nil];
```

After you dismiss it or remove it, just call:-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dissmissAViewController" object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had to rework the code a little but it's pretty spot on for what I needed :).